# how to use PublishPipelineArtifact@1 with build script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've got my yaml to run my build (which is a fake script), and I want to publish various outputs from the build script as an artifact.

I've half got it working, but I can't work out quite how to get some specific folder to be output.

```
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: Publish Report
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/s/ReportProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1
      artifactName: MyReport
```

what it actually seems to do is take some arbritrary folder (which is the name of my pipeline with the below as subfolders)

```
subfolders 
TestResults
a
b
s
```

yes, my app is in there, but so is everything, very odd.

I change the path...it publishes the same thing i.e. everything!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to refer to the folders in the build agent. You should know what the exact folders they are mapped to. See below example of a self-hosted agent:

[image]

`$(Pipeline.Workspace)` is mapped to `c:\agent\_work\1`

`$(Agent.BuildDirectory)` is also mapped to `c:\agent\_work\1`

`$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` is mapped to the `a` folder `c:\agent\_work\1\a`

`$(Build.BinariesDirectory)` is mapped to the `b` folder `c:\agent\_work\1\b`

`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` is the same as `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` which is mapped to the `s` folder `c:\agent\_work\1\s`

The default working directory for the PublishPipelineArtifact task and also other tasks is `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` (ie. `c:\agent\_work\1\s`)

Since your project folder resides in the folder `ReportProject` under `s`folder.  That's why `targetPath: 'ReportProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1'` works. Because it equals to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ReportProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1`, and
`$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/ReportProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1`,and `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ReportProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1`. These will all work.

Answer (score 2):

I used the yaml tooling in azure devops and that seemed to do this

```
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: Publish Report
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/ReportProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1'
      artifact: 'MyReport'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

that works, I don't especially like knowing that the agent puts the repository in a folder called "s", but apart from that, it works.

---

this also works

```
  targetPath: 'ReportProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1'
```

(I tried to get Build.SourcesDirectory to work but it failed)

Comment: By using `Build.SourcesDirectory` you should get the path including the 's' folder (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services)

Comment: doesnt seem to work for me. ##[error]Path does not exist: D:\a\1\s\$(PipelineBuild.SourcesDirectory)\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1